# Why didn't spelling of words keep track of pronunciation changes during the great vowel shift?

Tags: orthography, great-vowel-shift

In the English language, words are written according to the way they were pronounced before the great vowel shift. Take e.g. the sentence: "I came from my house, now I'm here". If we pronounce this according the sounds of the letters in the words, then we get close to the correct pronunciation in the year 1400:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hqQpziIETo&t=341s

Or take the word "nightingale", which in the 1400s used to be pronounced as written:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWI_dFxbzyg&t=287s

So, why didn't the spelling change with these gradual changes in pronunciation during the great vowel shift?

Comment: Printing had a significant effect.

Comment: Before printing, people spelled as they pleased, and tried to make the letters sound like they spoke. This was not fixed spelling; the idea that there was a fixed spelling for every word that all children had to learn and use forever and pass on to generations to come is a very strange notion. Speech changes, why shouldn't writing? Because printing and books and teachers.

Comment: The word was the same but the pronunciation changed? Most English words don't change spelling to match pronunciation.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to write an actual answer, but part of it is that people tend not to be aware of their pronunciation changing. If I'm used to writing "from", I'm probably gonna keep writing it that way, even if the way I pronounce it is now closer to "fram". And then add in what Prof. Lawler said about printing and books and teachers, and you get the current mix of fossilization and "OK, sure, we can standardize, but whose pronunciation are we gonna use?"